# Typeerror : 'todo.find is not a function'

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express

- I'm adding a new Model to my app but it's failing with "TypeError: todo.find is not a function". I have another model, Items, that are set up in the same way and are working fine. Things seem to be failing in the route but it works if I hook it up to the Item model. don't know what's going on wrong?

model

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');

    var todoSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
        name: {
            type: String,
            required: true,
            maxlength:32,
            trim:true
        }
    },{timestamps:true}
    )
    
    module.exports = mongoose.model('Todo',todoSchema)
```

auth.js//route

```
 var express = require('express');
    var router = express.Router();
    const {getAllTodos} = require('../controller/auth');
    
    router.post('/getalltodo',getAllTodos);
    
    module.exports = router;
```

auth.js//controller

```
 const Todo = require('../model/todo');
exports.getAllTodos = (req,res) =>{
    const todo = new Todo(req.body)

    todo.find().exec((err,todo) =>{
        if(err || !todo){
            return res.status(400).json({
                error : 'No Todos found'
            })
        }
        res.json(todo);
    })
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a problem in your `getAllTodos` middleware. You try to do this:

```
const todo = new Todo(req.body); // returns a Document

todo.find()...  // a Document doesn't have a 'find' method
```

You don't have a `find` method on a `Document` but you do have one on a `Model`.

Do this instead:

```
Todo.find()...
```

Look at the [docs](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api/model.html#model_Model.find) if you need more info.